# AKS: IP whitelisting (ingress)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to whitelist IP(s) on the ingress in the AKS. I am currently using the `ingress-nginx` not installed with Helm.

The mandatory kubernetes resources  can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml)

The service is started as:

```
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

Full yaml [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/cloud-generic.yaml)

My ingress definition is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  # namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /xx-xx
        backend:
          serviceName: xx-xx
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /xx
        backend:
          serviceName: /xx
          servicePort: 5432
```

The IP whitelisting is not enforced. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Hi, I do not see the k8s service for the nginx in your link, there are deployments, roles clusterroles, configmaps

Comment: @SureshVishnoi My bad. updated.

Comment: can you check your logs for what source IP address is seen by the ingress controller? have you seen this discussion: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2096

Comment: Perhaps, you need to provide a ranger or cidr format rather than single IP "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" ?

Comment: @MarkusDresch thanks. yes I did look into that issue and checked my configs. did not help.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi Thanks. Usually for single blocks (`/32`s) we don't need to specify CIDR ranges but to be sure I also checked with adding a /32 to my singular whitelist IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging around I found that the problem is because of this bug in NATing, defined [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/785) and there is quick medium read [here](https://medium.com/@chatelain.io/aks-azure-kubernetes-service-ingress-ip-filtering-whitelisting-issue-c194190df696).

Hope this solves problems for future readers or help track the bug